# Algorithm for scheduling optimum record list

Tags: performance, algorithm, language-agnostic, scheduling

Im looking for an algorithm for generating an optimum record list for a recording device given the following items list:

[Image link here http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/7952/recordlist.png](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/7952/recordlist.png)

At the moment the constraints are:

- No overlaps must exist.
- Compromise between compute speed and solved conflicts.

In the future it's possible more options will be added:

- Possibility for the user to have several recording devices.
- Possibility for the user to establish recording priorities for his/her favourites programmes (  1 highest -  3 lowest ).

The context is as follows:

- Items list is 1 week as maximum.(current time - current time + 1 week)
- Average items list size is 100 items and 300 maximum.

Also I would like to know if there is a way to generate the most optimum possible record list ( highest percentage of programmes sent to record)
in the case we cannot solve the 100% of the conflicts regardless of the processing time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you define optimality, what is the objective?

Comment: If you want an elegant, fun way to solve this, use a genetic algorithm. If you just want to do it quickly and move on, use greedy. I'm not sure if this is NP-complete. Also, please describe the format of inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
class Recording
{
    public int ProgrammeId { get; set; }
    public string ProgrammeTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string ChannelName { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get { return 1; } } // Constant weight
}
```

A greedy approach would be to consider the programs in order of increasing `start_time`. If a program is compatible with the previously selected programs, select it:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Recording> GreedySelection(IList<Recording> data)
{
    data = data
        .OrderBy(r => r.StartTime)
        .ThenBy(r => r.EndTime)
        .ToList();

    DateTime? lastEnd = null;
    foreach (var rec in data)
    {
        if (lastEnd == null || rec.StartTime >= lastEnd.Value)
        {
            yield return rec;
            lastEnd = rec.EndTime;
        }
    }
}
```

To get the optimal weighted solution, you could use dynamic programming:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Recording> WeightedSelection(IList<Recording> data)
{
    data = data
        .OrderBy(r => r.EndTime)
        .ThenBy(r => r.StartTime)
        .ToList();

    int count = data.Count;
    var lastCompatible = new int?[count];

    // Compute the closest program before in time, that is compatible.
    // This nested loop might be optimizable in some way.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (data[j].EndTime <= data[i].StartTime)
            {
                lastCompatible[i] = j;
                break; // inner loop
            }
        }
    }

    // Dynamic programming to calculate the best path
    var optimalWeight = new int[count];
    var cameFrom = new int?[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int weightWithItem = data[i].Weight;
        if (lastCompatible[i] != null)
        {
            weightWithItem += optimalWeight[lastCompatible[i].Value];
        }

        int weightWithoutItem = 0;
        if (i > 0) weightWithoutItem = optimalWeight[i-1];

        if (weightWithItem < weightWithoutItem)
        {
            optimalWeight[i] = weightWithoutItem;
            cameFrom[i] = i - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            optimalWeight[i] = weightWithItem;
            cameFrom[i] = lastCompatible[i];
        }
    }

    // This will give the programs in reverse order.
    for (int? i = count - 1; i != null; i = cameFrom[i.Value])
    {
        yield return data[i.Value];
    }
}
```

Not that this version incorporates weight, and tries to maximize the weight sum. If all weights are set to one (1), the size of the results of both algorithms will have the same size, since size equals weight.

Result of greedy:

```
ProgrammeTitle           StartTime         EndTime
Star Trek                2012-09-03 02:05  2012-09-03 03:05
Everybody Loves Raymond  2012-09-03 06:00  2012-09-03 07:00
CSI                      2012-09-03 07:00  2012-09-03 08:00
Mythbusters              2012-09-03 08:00  2012-09-03 09:00
CSI                      2012-09-03 10:00  2012-09-03 11:00
Mythbusters              2012-09-03 11:00  2012-09-03 12:00
Star Trek                2012-09-04 02:05  2012-09-04 03:05
Everybody Loves Raymond  2012-09-04 06:00  2012-09-04 07:00
CSI                      2012-09-04 07:00  2012-09-04 08:00
Mythbusters              2012-09-04 08:00  2012-09-04 09:00
CSI                      2012-09-04 10:00  2012-09-04 11:00
Mythbusters              2012-09-04 11:00  2012-09-04 12:00
```

Result of dynamic (sorted):

```
ProgrammeTitle           StartTime         EndTime
Everybody Loves Raymond  2012-09-03 03:00  2012-09-03 04:00
Everybody Loves Raymond  2012-09-03 06:00  2012-09-03 07:00
CSI                      2012-09-03 07:00  2012-09-03 08:00
CSI                      2012-09-03 08:30  2012-09-03 09:30
CSI                      2012-09-03 10:00  2012-09-03 11:00
Star Trek                2012-09-03 11:05  2012-09-03 12:05
Everybody Loves Raymond  2012-09-04 03:00  2012-09-04 04:00
Everybody Loves Raymond  2012-09-04 06:00  2012-09-04 07:00
CSI                      2012-09-04 07:00  2012-09-04 08:00
CSI                      2012-09-04 08:30  2012-09-04 09:30
CSI                      2012-09-04 10:00  2012-09-04 11:00
Star Trek                2012-09-04 11:05  2012-09-04 12:05
```

The algorithms are based on this document:

- [cs.princeton.edu/courses/.../06dynamic-programming.pdf](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos423/lectures/06dynamic-programming.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Use [First Fit Decreasing](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e4620) and [Tabu Search](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e5078).

This use case is very similar to nurse rostering ([see this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nPagqJK3bs)): instead of assigning shifts to nurses, you're assigning items to recorders, where recorders is a list of [recorder1, notRecorded].